# Related products based on keywords

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Currently im using “Converio” wordpress theme. Related products is working by default on the basis of same category/sub-category, I want related products to be displayed based on “keyword”,”title”,”description”.

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct that you're meaning products as in WooCommerce products?

If so:

Right before WooCommerce returns the related products for a current product(if you're not on a product page you could define a `post_id` yourself). It uses a filter which you can hook into.

```
$related_posts = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products', $related_posts, $product_id, array(
    'limit'        => $limit,
    'excluded_ids' => $exclude_ids,
) );
```

By using the following filter within your child-theme/theme:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products, function( $related_posts ) {
    // Add or replace products to $related_posts.     

    return $related_posts;
}, 10, 1 );
```